Server flask with Gunicorn and Nginx does not receive custom headers
I have a VPS configured weith a server with a certbot SSL certificate and with Nginx and Gunicorn for a Flask application.
The server works with the domain correctly, the problem is when a request is made with headers, the server does not receive them.
These are the headers that the server receives:
DEBUG:root:Host: myweb.com
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.37.3
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 27fd8606-d9ce-4120-9a68-c359b3fe0e60
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

This is my Flask app code.  I tried to configure the app with cors to support any connection and to support the headers needed:
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, send_file
import os
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_cors import cross_origin
import requests
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='flask_debug.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins='*')

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Api_key")
    return response

def verify_api_key(api_key):
    response = requests.get(
        "https://myweb.com/api/verify-api-key", headers={'Api_key': api_key}
    )

    if response.status_code == 200:
        result = response.json()
        return result.get("isValid", False)
    else:
        return False

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'El servidor está en línea y funcionando !'

@app.route("/api/get-user-videos", methods=["GET"])
def get_user_videos():
    api_key = request.headers.get("Api_key")
    if not api_key:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Se requiere una API_KEY'}), 401
    
    username = request.args.get("username")
    if not username:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Se requiere un nombre de usuario'}), 400

    if not verify_api_key(api_key):
        return jsonify({'error': 'API_KEY no válida'}), 401

    user_videos_folder = os.path.join("results", username)
    if not os.path.isdir(user_videos_folder):
        return jsonify({'error': 'Usuario no encontrado'}), 404

    video_files = [
        f
        for f in os.listdir(user_videos_folder)
        if f.endswith(".mp4")
    ]

    if not video_files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Usuario sin videos'}), 404
        
    return jsonify(video_files), 200

        
@app.route("/api/get-user-videos-list", methods=["GET"])
def get_user_videos_list():
    api_key = request.headers.get("Api_key")
    logging.debug(request.headers)
    if not api_key:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Se requiere una API_KEY'}), 401

    if not verify_api_key(api_key):
        return jsonify({'error': 'API_KEY no válida'}), 401
    
    username = request.args.get("username")
    if not username:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Se requiere un nombre de usuario'}), 401

    user_videos_folder = os.path.join("uploads", username)
    if not os.path.isdir(user_videos_folder):
        return jsonify({'error': 'Usuario no encontrado'}), 404

    video_files = [
        f
        for f in os.listdir(user_videos_folder)
        if f.endswith(".mp4")
    ]

    if not video_files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Usuario sin videos'}), 404
    
    alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    missing_letters = [letter for letter in alphabet if letter not in ''.join(video_files)]
    
    if not missing_letters:
        return jsonify(video_files), 200

    return jsonify({'error': 'Alfabeto incompleto !'}), 400

@app.route("/api/get-user-video/<username>/<video_name>", methods=["GET"])
def get_user_video(username, video_name):
    api_key = request.headers.get("Api_key")
    if not api_key:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Se requiere una API_KEY'}), 401

    if not verify_api_key(api_key):
        return jsonify({'error': 'API_KEY no válida'}), 401
    
    if not username:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Se requiere un username'}), 401

    user_video_path = os.path.join("uploads", username, video_name)
    if not os.path.isfile(user_video_path):
        return jsonify({'error': 'Video no encontrado'}), 404

    return send_file(user_video_path, as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)

This is the service file for starting gunicorn:
[Unit]
Description=Server Videos
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/videos/flask-server-videos
Environment="PATH=/home/videos/env/videos/bin"
ExecStart=/home/videos/env/videos/bin/gunicorn --workers 2 --bind unix:app.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

This is the configuration file for the nginx server, I also tried to allow the headers needed for the Flask app but they are still not received:
server {
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/videos/flask-server-videos/app.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myweb.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myweb.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = myweb.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name myweb.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

This is the request I am sending, either from a web site, or with Postman:
curl "https://myweb.com/api/get-user-videos-list?username=Jorge" ^
  -H "Accept: */*" ^
  -H "Accept-Language: es,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es-MX;q=0.7" ^
  -H "Api_key: abcdefgh123456789" ^
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" ^
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
  -H "Origin: https://anotherweb.com" ^
  -H "Referer: https://myweb.com/" ^
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edg/124.0.0.0" ^
  -H ^"sec-ch-ua: ^\^"Chromium^\^";v=^\^"124^\^", ^\^"Microsoft Edge^\^";v=^\^"124^\^", ^\^"Not-A.Brand^\^";v=^\^"99^\^"^" ^

Similar problem
I tried this solution, I modified the nginx configuration file, added the directive underscores_in_headers on;, but it still doesn't receive the headers.

how do you check headers in requests in Flask?

In my code, I just log 'request.headers', and it shows me all the headers received.

Does this answer your question? Flask is not getting application specific headers added through javascript

I just tried it, I modified the nginx configuration file, I added the directive underscores_in_headers on;, but no, it still doesn't receive the headers.
@Dmitry
